# Calling multiple methods for one object simultaneously?

Tags: python, methods

Im just beginning to learn python. I would like to know why performing the following on the file object generates an error ?

```
 ex = open(file).seek(10).readline()
```

Can i not call multiple methods for the file object ?

Comment: Hint: what is the return type of `seek`?

Comment: If you read the error, it tells you why this doesn't work!

Comment: I just read, that it has no return value. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling multiple methods to the file object, but calling the seek method to the file object, and the readline one to the object returned by the seek method.

Content of data.txt:

```
Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world!
```

Content of main.py:

```
fname = 'data.txt'

fid = open(fname)

a = fid.seek(10)
print a, type(a)

b = fid.readline()
print b, type(b)
```

Return:

```
None <type 'NoneType'>
ld! Hello, world! Hello, world!
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: I've understood now . Thank you !